# Unsupported Media Type when using Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to use public Web Api from: https://www.xbtce.cc/tradeapi.

So here is a code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var url = "https://cryptottdemowebapi.xbtce.net:8443/api/v1/public/tick";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And result is:

```
{StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2016 16:03:45 GMT
    Content-Length: 0
}}
```

This error continue even after adding request headers with "application/json". 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a broken server implementation, given if I load that URL in my browser, it most definitely returns `application/json` as the Content-Type for the response. It's not strictly correct, but might work for this (seemingly) broken server to pass an Accept header with wildcards, e.g. `*/*` and see if that helps.

Comment: Seems to here: https://gist.github.com/petejohanson/d00537163fce8a99b60be06acbeb9a8a Try using Fiddler or other tool to inspect the request headers and be sure it's sending the correct Accept header.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the gzip
below the correct code

```
var client = new HttpClient(new PublicContentHandler());
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_webApiAddress);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
public class PublicContentHandler : HttpClientHandler
        {
            public PublicContentHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            }
        }
```

Refer  the [link](https://github.com/SoftFx/TTWebClient-CSharp) with the bunch of c# examples.